# Can I make VS Code remember the last input string to a task?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I created a task that invokes my custom build system. It works, but every time I run it it I have to retype the target name input string. I'd like it to remember the last one and autofill that, not the default value. Is there a way to do that?

```json
// tasks.json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "buildsys",
            "command": "buildsys build ${input:target}",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "options": {
                "env": {
                    "PATH": "${env:PATH}:/Dev/BuildSystem/bin"
                }
            },
            "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
            "detail": "My custom build task"
        }
    ],

    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "target",
            "description": "Target:",
            "default": "FooApp",
            "type": "promptString"
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the extension I made [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#promptstringremember) and the command `extension.commandvariable.promptStringRemember`

> If you have given a key attribute the Input Box will be prefilled with:
>
> - first call in session: the default value
> - next call in session: the previous value

Comment: I couldn't make this work for a pickFile command, is there an example somewhere? Just need the first time to prompt and 2nd time to default on last pick.

Comment: @ShlomoGottlieb where is the 2nd time, a new task execution or within the same task a reuse of the picked file path, within same task execution use `extension.commandvariable.remember` command

Comment: @ShlomoGottlieb Maybe create an issue at the repo and show more info on the task you want to complete

Comment: I want to run the same task twice in a row, and have the 2nd time pre-select the pick from the first time (show the same pickfile list options but fill the input field with the previous pick).

Comment: @ShlomoGottlieb have a look at the `run cpplint` example shown in the `pickStringRemember` command, delete the `showDirs` property

Comment: thanks!!
from the name I'm guessing you're the extension developer so thank you for it, it's truly amazing and capable.